# Transition in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three different boxes in same row. I want transition in those boxes when clicked inside the box. 
[image]
Right now when i click on any box it will expand from left to right and get full width and other boxes are stacked in next row. What i want is when i click red box the that box must expand from left to right overlapping the remaining boxes.
Similarly when i click the green box, it must expand from both its side and overlap both boxes in left and right side and get full width. Similarly when i click blue box it must expand from left side and fill the width overlapping the remaining boxes. 
Can any one please help me?

My Code is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Transition</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .box {
        width:30%;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 10px;
        float:left;
    }
    #first {
        background-color: red;
    }
    #second {
        background-color: green;
    }
    #third {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="first" class="box"></div>
        <div id="second" class="box"></div>
        <div id="third" class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var containerWidth = $(".container").width();
            $(".box").click(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#"+id).animate({width: "100%"});
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/m157u2yw/)

Comment: use position to overlap

Comment: Will those boxes ultimately have just a background color/image in them, or actual content/text? I think how to go about this depends on that, and if it is content, then on how specifically you want that to behave at the different box widths resp. during the transition ... (be laid out in final size from the beginning and shown cut off initially, stretch or adapt to the width, ...?)

Comment: if you want overlap then you can also width:0; other box on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition `transform: scale()`, and that will allow the element to expand over the others. You can just assign a class via js for that property to transition and you can do that in pure CSS. And since each element is 20% wide, transitioning `scaleX(5)` would be 100%. And use `transform-origin` to change which direction the elements expand from.

```js
var containerWidth = $(".container").width();
$(".box").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $(this).addClass('scale');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width:20%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  float:left;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#first {
  background-color: red;
}
#second {
  background-color: green;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
#third {
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.scale {
  transform: scaleX(5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="first" class="box"></div>
  <div id="second" class="box"></div>
  <div id="third" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Though this effect would work a lot better if the elements were evenly spaced within the parent, then they will overlap and fill the parent evenly. Using `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` on the parent enables that.

```js
var containerWidth = $(".container").width();
$(".box").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $(this).addClass('scale');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  width:20%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#first {
  background-color: red;
}
#second {
  background-color: green;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
#third {
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.scale {
  transform: scaleX(5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="first" class="box"></div>
  <div id="second" class="box"></div>
  <div id="third" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another situation. What if i have 4 boxes instead of 3 boxes. What will happen to the `transform-origin` property