# Scale transition in four divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question is related to one that i have already created [transition-in-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078664/transition-in-div) . I didnot get answer for my next issue there so i decided to create new question.
I have four boxes and i want the transition effect in all four boxes. 
[image] 
What i want is whenever i click on any box, the width of that box must increase from its side to the left and right to fit the full width. Right now it only fills some portion of width.
My Code is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Transition</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  width:20%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#first {
  background-color: red;
}
#second {
  background-color: green;
  transform-origin: 25% 75%;
}
#third {
  background-color: aqua;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
#fourth {
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.scale {
  transform: scaleX(4);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="first" class="box"></div>
        <div id="second" class="box"></div>
        <div id="third" class="box"></div>
        <div id="fourth" class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var containerWidth = $(".container").width();
        $(".box").click(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          $(this).addClass('scale');
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m157u2yw/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tweak around your CSS a lil bit:

Since your .box width is 20%, your scaleX() is 5,

Then just go ahead and fix your Transform-origins so it covers out correctly:
https://jsfiddle.net/m157u2yw/8/

```
.box {
  width:20%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#first {
  background-color: red;
}
#second {
  background-color: green;
  transform-origin: 33.33%;
}
#third {
  background-color: aqua;
  transform-origin: 66.66%;
}
#fourth {
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: 100%;
}
.scale {
  transform: scaleX(5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a small mathematical error, you are scaling each div to 4x when their size is 20% so their new size is now 80% instead of the full 100% width.

Please consider the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m157u2yw/7/

For previewing purposes I've made it so if you click on an expanded box it resets back so you can quickly play with it.

I'm using width instead of scale as it will be useful in case these squares actually have some content inside (scaling would distort it).

I'm also adding another class `.scale-down` to the not-clicked divs to make sure they also animate out leaving the full space to the expanded one.

Comment: This is what i wanted except other boxes goes decrease in width.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the boxes in containers and animate the width, something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pt1vk0c1/

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="first" class="box-container">
          <div class="box"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="second" class="box-container">
          <div class="box"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="third" class="box-container">
          <div class="box"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fourth" class="box-container">
          <div class="box"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box-container {
  width:25%;
  height: 200px;
}

.box {
  width:80%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: width .5s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#first .box {
  background-color: red;
}
#second .box {
  background-color: green;
  transform-origin: 25% 75%;
}
#third .box {
  background-color: aqua;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
#fourth .box {
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.scale {
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: The boxes are filling the empty space only. i wanted to cover whole width of container.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work regardless of the number of boxes or their width. Better to avoid any magic numbers if possible.

Transition width instead of transform. You won't need any transform origins and it will work with any number of boxes regardless of the box size.

To make the width of the other boxes 0. You can add a class to the container.
Than use

```
.container.open .box:not(.scale) {
  width: 0;
}
```

to set the width of any box without the class .scale to 0

http://codepen.io/flurrd/pen/xqmwLN

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: width .5s;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.scale {
  width: 100%;
}

.container.open .box:not(.scale) {
  width: 0;
}
```

JS

```
var containerWidth = $(".container").width();
$(".box").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $(this).toggleClass('scale');
  $(".container").toggleClass('open')
});
```